# How to get mat-sidenav-content to take 100% of height using Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

How to get mat-sidenav-content to take 100% of height using Angular Material

So I have a side-nav and can't seem to get it to occupy 100% of the height.
It gets cut off as you can see in the image.
Using latest Angular 8 and Material latest.

You can see the main component css here:
https://github.com/born2net/studiopro-web/blob/master/src/app/layouts/main/main.component.scss

if I force it via

```
<div fxLayout="row" class="container" style="background-color: darkslategray; min-height: 2000px">
```

it works but of course I do not want to hard code height at 2000px
and how it looks like here:

Sean

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this solved the issue:

```
.container {
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
```

Comment: It will raise some other issue for scolling